# Knockout POST sends empty class

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

Using this article http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/knockout-js-and-bootstrap-with-asp-net-mvc-part-2 to get the knockout/ajax syntax I'v written a `PartialView` that generates the following html and javascript:

```
<div id="psuAccordion" class="list-group">


    <a class="list-group-item accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sbarQuickClientAdd">Quick Client Add</a>
    <div id="sbarQuickClientAdd" class="panel-body collapse in" style="height: auto;">

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Client Name: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium" data-bind="value: ClientName" ,="" placeholder="Company">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Contact Name: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium" data-bind="value: ContactName" ,="" placeholder="Contact">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Phone: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium" data-bind="value: Phone" ,="" placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Email: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium" data-bind="value: Email" ,="" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls" style="padding-top: 15px;">


               <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-bind="click: btnCxlQuickClientAdd"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
               <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right" data-bind="click: btnCreQuickClientAdd"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         var avpQuickClientAdd = {
             TemplateName: ko.observable(),
             ClientName : ko.observable(), ContactName : ko.observable(), Phone : ko.observable(), Email : ko.observable(),
             btnCxlQuickClientAdd: function () {
                 $(this).closest('.accordion-toggle').click();
             },
             btnCreQuickClientAdd: function () {
                 this.TemplateName("QuickClientAdd");

                 $.ajax( {
                     url: '/QuickForm/Create',
                     type: 'post',
                     dataType: 'json',
                     data: ko.toJSON(this),
                     contentType: 'application/json',
                     success: function (result) {
                        // clear the form 

                     },
                     error: function (err) {
                           alert(err.responseText);
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                    }
                }
            );}
      }

      ko.applyBindings(avpQuickClientAdd);

  });
</script> 


</div>
```

If I enter some data into the `form` and click the save button, I can see in the chrome debugger that the ko.toJSON is making the object and populating it but the controller method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AVP.DAL;

namespace AVP.Controllers
{
    public class QuickFormController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /QuickForm/
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Create(QuickFormClient qfc)
        {
            string clientName = qfc.ClientName;
            return new JsonResult();
        }

    }
}
```

receive an empty object.  The controller method returning a new `JsonResult` is irrelevant for now.  This is clearly a stub method just to test the posting mechanism.  The issue is that the data is not getting to the server.

This is the argument type definition:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AVP.DAL
{
    public class QuickFormClient 
    {
        public string TemplateName;
        public string ClientName;
        public string ContactName;
        public string Phone;
        public string Email;
    }
}
```

The members are in the same order as declared in the KO VieWModel.

I have also tried these syntax variants with varying degrees of failure:

```
-1- data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON())
-2- data: "{ qfc: " + JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON()) + "}"
-3- data: "{ qfc: " + ko.toJSON() + "}"
-4- data: JSON.stringify({qfc: ko.toJSON()})
```

**EDIT:**

After first answer given I tried JSON.stringify(ko.ToJS) and the controller method still receives an object whose members are all `null`.

http://pdvstheweb.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/httpstackoverflowcomquestions22350097kn.html

**EDIT:**

The answer is a combination of Hans's answer and adding `{ get; set; }` to the members of `QuickFormClient`.

Thanks guys.

**EDIT:**

It doesn't work with polymorphism tho.

```
public class QuickForm 
{
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }
}

public class QuickFormClient : QuickForm
{ 
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
} 

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(QuickForm arg)
{
    switch(arg.TemplateName)
    {
        case "QuickClient" :
           QuickFormClient c = (QuickFormClient)arg;
           break;
    }
}
```

When the controller method is called, `TemplateName` is null.

I don't know how much value is added by having it work this way since it's easy enough to write controller methods for the different form types and the knockout javascript has to be separate objects, right?  I guess maybe there's some javascript magic could be performed to make the Knockout viewmodel have dynamic properties?  But even if that's possible, is MVC's type mapping magic even *supposed* to work with polymorphism?

Comment: Use ko.toJS instead of ko.toJSON

Comment: FYI - When I tried this I got a "global object does not contain member TemplateName" just before the ajax call when setting the value of the TemplateName observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way would be `data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(this))` (assuming that `this` indeed points to your viewmodel, which it seems to do.

`ko.toJS` creates a plain JavaScript object (without the observable-wrappers)

`JSON.stringify` is only necessary because your ajax call says `contentType: 'application/json'`. Generally there's no need to send as JSON, though in some cases (with complex objects beings sent, especially objects containing lists/arrays) stringifying will help the MVC model mapper to understand what you're sending.

Comment: ko.toJSON() is wrapper over JSON.stringify(). so i think whether you do ko.toJSON(this) or JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(this)) both are same.

Comment: That didn't work.  I still get a null object.  I posted a screenshot of the debugger displaying that "this" really does point to the right object.

Comment: ahhh... the getter and setters. I totally overlooked the C#-part :( good that you found it.